# How to use scipy's minimize (with constraints) within a class?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Sorry my post was not clear. I am trying to build a `class` for the following problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
n, y = 1.0, 100

def func(x, sign=1.0, beta=0.90):
    """Objective function"""
    return sign*(np.log(x[0]) + beta * np.log(x[1]))

def func_deriv(x, sign=1.0, beta=0.90):
    """Derivative of objective function"""
    dfdx0 = sign*(1/x[0])
    dfdx1 = sign*beta*(1/x[1])
    return np.array ([dfdx0, dfdx1])    
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[0] + x[1]/n - y]),
        'jac': lambda x: np.array([1, 1/n])})

resC = minimize (func, [30,20], args=(-1.0,),    
                 jac=func_deriv, constraints=cons,
                 method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
print(resC.x)
```

The results is:
[52.64537904 47.35462096]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried/figured so far? For such kind of questions a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is critical, so, please, provide one.

Comment: @Suthiro I edited my post above - hope it makes more sense. thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need/want to use a class?